# SVProgressHUD HUD is changing position on screen

Tags: swift, svprogresshud

I have a weird behavior with SVProgressHUD.
When I launch it : SVProgressHUD.show(), the HUD appears above the center and 1-2 second after, it goes down to the center.
I want to have it directly in the center of the View. By the way, I have let nothing in my Viewcontroller and its view.

Comment: show the code where you set SVProgressHUD properties and where in your view controller do you show it.

Comment: I have'nt set any properties. I just called the SVProgessHUD.show() before sending some request and call SVProgressHUD.dismiss() on the main queue when the request is done

Comment: all you did was SVProgressHUD.show() ?